# Android NDK build script ignoring main makefile

Tags: stl, makefile, android-ndk

I've got Application.mk file which is ignored by ndk-build for some reason.
What i've got in it:

```
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(call my-dir)
APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_OPTIM := debug
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

And flags on build is still:

```
-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti
```

And no gnustl includes.

What can be the problem?

Comment: May be you should try this
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the `Application.mk` is inside the `jni` folder, alongside the `Android.mk`.